# Divide words in one column to three equal columns using Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, command-line, operating-system

Given a multi-line file, such that each line has one word on it, I would like to generate a new file that is comprised of sentences. The sentences generated should be words from the input file. Specifically every third word.

Example input:

> how
>   are
>   you
>   my
>   friend
>   i
>   missed
>   you

Desired Output:

> how my missed
>   are friend you
>   you i

I am sure there is a clever way to accomplish this using `sed` or `awk` or `perl` or some similar tool.

Comment: Could you give this a try, and let us know how you get on? `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that your original file is called `orig` and the file you wish to create is called `new`

```sh
awk '(NR+2) % 3 == 0' orig | tr '\n' ' ' > new
printf "\n" >> new
awk '(NR+1) % 3 == 0' orig | tr '\n' ' ' >> new
printf "\n" >> new
awk '(NR+0) % 3 == 0' orig | tr '\n' ' ' >> new
printf "\n" >> new
```

What is this madness? This is SPARTA! And also some neat `awk` stuff

1. `awk 'NR % 3 == 0' file` will print out every `3'rd` line of file
2. `awk '(NR+1) % 3 == 0' file` will print out every `3'rd` line of file but with an offset of `1`
3. `tr '\n' ' '` will *translate* all newlines to spaces
4. The `>` and `>>` symbols are used to redirect program output to a file and mean *overwrite* and append *respectively*.

[Useful post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369181/printing-every-nth-line-out-of-a-large-file-into-a-new-file)

Comment: it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variable solution that allows you to select every `N'th` line assuming your original file is called `orig` and the file you wish to create is called `new`.

```sh
N=2

i=0
rm -f new
for j in `seq 0 $N`
do
    i=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        [ $i -eq $j ] && printf "${line} " >> new
        i=$(( (i+1) % ${N} ))
    done < orig
    printf '\n' >> new
done
```

This script simply reads the file line by line and uses modulo to determine weather the current line is to be appended or not. Simply change the `N=3` at the top of the script to do every `2nd` line or every `5th` line.